# How do you reset my tmux display? Its stuck in a smaller window

Tags: tmux, terminal-multiplexer

for some reason my tmux is stuck in a smaller box. what is the reason for this? And how can I reset my display? Yes i know i can just kill the pane, but i have a bunch of sessions i want to keep.

http://prntscr.com/85r0og

[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple sessions attached?  SO had a discussion similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814612/is-there-any-way-to-redraw-tmux-window-when-switching-smaller-monitor-to-bigger

Comment: Have you detached the window and re-attached just to see if that worked?

Answer (score 2):

A useful setting for this is

```
setw -g aggressive-resize on
```

added to ~/.tmux.conf. It causes tmux to resize a window based on the smallest client actually viewing it, not on the smallest one attached to the entire session.

Taken from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux